# $Q(a,i)$ is isomorphic to a quotient of $ \mathbb Q[X,Y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Let $a\in \mathbb C$ be a 3rd root of 2, i.e. $a$ has minimal polynomial $X^3-2$ over $ \mathbb Q$.
Claim: $ \mathbb Q[X,Y]/(X^3-2,Y^2+1) \cong  \mathbb Q(a,i)$

How do I see this, do I need to consider the evaluation map $f \mapsto f(a,i)$ or is it easier to work with $Q[X,Y]\cong Q[X][Y]$ and evaluation in one variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we clearly have a surjective homomorphism

$$\mathbb Q[X,Y]/(X^3-2,Y^2+1) \to \mathbb Q(a,i),$$

given by evaluation. To show injectivity, it suffices to show that the left hand side is actually a field:

Note that, for any ring (commutative, with $1$), we have

$$R[X,Y]/(f(X),g(Y)) \cong (R[X]/(f))[Y]/(g(Y)) \cong (R[Y]/(g))[X]/(f(X)).$$

In particular

$$\mathbb Q[X,Y]/(X^3-2,Y^2+1) \cong (\mathbb Q[X]/(X^3-2))[Y]/(Y^2+1) \cong \mathbb Q(a)[Y]/(Y^2+1)$$

and

$$\mathbb Q[X,Y]/(X^3-2,Y^2+1) \cong (\mathbb Q[Y]/(Y^2+1))[X]/(X^3-2) \cong \mathbb Q(i)[X]/(X^3-2)$$

Hence, in order to conclude, you have to show one of the following equaivalent statements:

- $Y^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q(a)$,
- $X^3-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q(i)$.

This is quite easy, you can either do some concrete calculations or argue with the degree of the field extensions (This always works, when they are co-prime).

---

Let me elaborate on the isomorphism

$$R[X,Y]/(f(X),g(Y)) \cong (R[X]/(f))[Y]/(g(Y)).$$

Let $A$ be any ring and $I \subset J \subset A$ ideals. We have the well known isomorphism theorem $$A/J \cong (A/I)/(J/I).$$

Using this with $I=(a), J=(a,b)$, it says

$$A/(a,b) \cong (A/(a))/(\overline b)$$

where $\overline b$ is the residue class of $b$ in $A/(a)$. You should keep this in mind as "If we divide out two elements, we can divide them out one after another".

In our situation, we obtain

$$R[X,Y]/(f(X),g(Y)) = (R[X,Y]/(f(X)))/(\overline g(Y)).$$

Now let $A$ be again any ring and $I \subset A$ some ideal. Then $I[x] = IA[x]$ is an ideal of $A[x]$, and we have $A[x]/I[x]=(A/I)[x]$.

Using this with $A=R[X]$ and $I=(f(X))$, we obtain

$$R[X,Y]/(f(X)) = (R[X]/(f))[Y].$$

Summarizing, this yields

$$R[X,Y]/(f(X),g(Y)) = (R[X,Y]/(f(X)))/(\overline g(Y)) = (R[X]/(f))[Y] / (\overline g(Y)).$$

Note that the coefficient of $g$ are elements of $\mathbb Q$ in our situation, hence they are not touched by dividing out $f$. So we can forget about the \overline and just write $g(Y)$.

Comment: We can of course generalize this as follows: Let $a,b$ be algebraic over some field $k$ with minimal polynomials $f_a,f_b$ respectively. Then $$k[X,Y]/(f_a(X),f_b(Y)) \cong k(a,b)$$ holds if and only if one of the following conditions hold:

1) $f_a$ is irreducible over $k(b)$.

2) $f_b$ is irreducible over $k(a)$.

3) $[k(a,b):k]=[k(a):k][k(b):k]$.

Comment: Note that co-primality of $[k(a):k]$ and $[k(b):k]$ is sufficient (but not necessary!) for these conditions to hold.

Comment: Have a look at my edit.

Comment: Thanks! I realize now that we didn't explicitly cover isomorphism theorems for rings (learning about rings before groups also didn't help there).